# How can I solve this error when using case_when?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm using this code:

```
ovabonnement <- ovabonnement %>%
  mutate(c12_ovabonnement_type_con_voor = case_when(s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_anders == 1 ~ NA,
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_1 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_13 == 1 ~ "Basis",
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_2 == 1 | 
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_3 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_4 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_9 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_11 == 1 ~ "Voordeel",
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_5 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_6 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_7 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_8 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_10 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_12 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_14 == 1 ~ "Vrij"))
```

So I have these 15 variables that represent whether a person has that subscription added onto their public transport membership. Because it was a multiple choice questionnaire people could select multiple choices, which is why they are different variables.

I want to make these into one variable that takes NA if people answered "other", "Basis" if people answered 1 or 13, "Voordeel" if people answered 2,3,4,9 or 11 and "Vrij" if people answered 5,6,7,8,10,12 or 14.

If people answered 2, there will be a 1 in s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_2. People can have answered multiple of these, which makes it a bit tricky. However, I want it to go through these chronologically. For example, if a person answered 2 AND 10, it should choose the 10, because the code is later, but I'm not sure if that is how case_when works.

I get this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `c12_ovabonnement_type_con_voor = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `names(message) <- `*vtmp*``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Please check if any of the column names mentioned are incorrectly spelled

Comment: Also, the first `NA` can be `NA_character_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when/if_else` are type sensitive i.e all the expressions should return the same type.  In the OP's expression, the first expression returns `NA` and NA by default is `logical`, and all others return `character` type.  We need `NA_character_` to match the type of others

```
ovabonnement <- ovabonnement %>%
  mutate(c12_ovabonnement_type_con_voor = case_when(s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_anders == 1 ~ NA_character_,
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_1 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_13 == 1 ~ "Basis",
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_2 == 1 | 
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_3 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_4 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_9 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_11 == 1 ~ "Voordeel",
                                                    s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_5 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_6 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_7 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_8 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_10 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_12 == 1 |
                                                      s2_ovabonnement_type_voor_14 == 1 ~ "Vrij"))
```